# Search and replace with wildcards in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, wildcard, vba

I use comma as decimal separator, but sometimes I receive files where values are below a set limit, and then the file uses point as "<2.5". Sometimes there is one digit before the decimal separator, and sometimes there are two digits.

I need to be able to replace the point with a comma in cells with begin with the "less than" symbol, but retain the actual numbers, so that "<2.5" is replaced with "<2,5" and "<10.0" is replaced with "<10,0". This needs to be done in Excel VBA.

I can't do a general search for "." and replace with ",", since there are places where I need to keep the point as it is.

Anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: if through VBA then look into RegEx

Comment: Can you recommend a good tutorial for RegEx? I can't make heads or tails of what I can find.

Comment: you can start with [This](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html)

Comment: @LarsS - added an array approach via `Replace` function to solve your *wildcards* question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(<[0-9]+)[\.]"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "$1,"
Dim myreplace As Long
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each cell In Myrange
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = cell.Value

        With RegEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If RegEx.Test(strInput) Then
             cell.Value = (RegEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))

        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach via `Replace` function**

You could read in data to a **datafield array**, replace the mentioned "<" data via `Replace` function and write them back in one statement by the following code. - Of course it's possible to use *RegEx*, too as mentioned in above comment.

**Notes**

a) I assume you are using data in column A:A via `Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & n)`; this can easily changed to any other range.

b) Assigning values to a variant datafield array automatically creates a one based 2-dim array, which you address in case of one column only e.g. via `v(1,1)`, `v(2,1)`, `v(3,1)` etc. to `v(n,1)`.

**Example Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub replaceLowerThan()
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")    ' << Change to your sheet name
Dim n       As Long, i As Long
Dim rng     As Range
Dim v
' get last row number and define data range
  n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & n)
' write data to 1-based 2-dim datafield array
  v = rng.Value2
' replace "<..." values
  For i = 1 To n
      If Not IsError(v(i, 1)) Then    ' omit cells with errors like #DIV/0!
         If v(i, 1) Like "<*" Then v(i, 1) = Replace(v(i, 1), ".", ",")
      End If
  Next i
' write values back
  rng.Value2 = v
End Sub
```

Comment: I went with a RegEx approach and found a solution what worked, but thanks for the alternative solution. I find the RegEx pattern syntax hard to comprehend, and this is easier to understand :)